# "failedLimitProcessingTime" on Design Automation Workitem

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I wrote a Design Automation Revit addin to export 3d geometry and material data from a RVT file. It has been working 100% in prod until last weekend.

Now when I POST a workitem, the workitem dont continue past below:

> [03/15/2021 11:24:29] End download phase successfully. [03/15/2021
> 11:24:29] Start preparing script and command line parameters.
> [03/15/2021 11:24:29] Command line: [ /i
> "T:\Aces\Jobs\d25b06b3501c47f9b123ac282aa2e531\file.rvt" /al
> "T:\Aces\Applications\CLIENT_NAME.REDACTED.PACKAGENAME_REDACTED[4].package"]
> [03/15/2021 11:24:29] End preparing script and command line
> parameters. [03/15/2021 11:24:29] Start script phase. [03/15/2021
> 11:24:29] ### Command line arguments: /isolate
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\Software\Autodesk\CoreUser\WorkItem_d25b06b3501c47f9b123ac282aa2e531
> "T:\Aces\Jobs\d25b06b3501c47f9b123ac282aa2e531\userdata" /exe
> "T:\Aces\AcesRoot\21.0\coreEngine\Exe\revitcoreconsole.exe"  /i
> "T:\Aces\Jobs\d25b06b3501c47f9b123ac282aa2e531\file.rvt" /al
> "T:\Aces\Applications\c096df734873f27f2b44f3de9e7e5843.3NtdG9abSFMTefGhKAFq6IpmzdOlAcxj.EnscapeImporter[4].package".
> [03/15/2021 11:24:29] Start Revit Core Engine standard output dump.
> [03/15/2021 11:24:29] Running in unattended mode. [03/15/2021
> 11:24:29] ====== Revit is running: revitcoreconsole ====== [03/15/2021
> 11:24:29] Current Exe path:
> T:\Aces\AcesRoot\21.0\coreEngine\Exe\revitcoreconsole.exe [03/15/2021
> 11:24:29] Echoing command line args: [03/15/2021 11:24:29]   0:/i
> [03/15/2021 11:24:29]
> 1:T:\Aces\Jobs\d25b06b3501c47f9b123ac282aa2e531\file.rvt [03/15/2021
> 11:24:29]   2:/al [03/15/2021 11:24:29]
> 3:T:\Aces\Applications\c096df734873f27f2b44f3de9e7e5843.3NtdG9abSFMTefGhKAFq6IpmzdOlAcxj.EnscapeImporter[4].package
> [03/15/2021 11:24:29]   4:/isolate [03/15/2021 11:24:29]
> 5:HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\Software\Autodesk\CoreUser\WorkItem_d25b06b3501c47f9b123ac282aa2e531
> [03/15/2021 11:24:29]
> 6:T:\Aces\Jobs\d25b06b3501c47f9b123ac282aa2e531\userdata [03/15/2021
> 11:24:29] Running RevitAssemblyResolver.... [03/15/2021 11:24:29]
> Initializing RevitCoreEngine... [03/15/2021 11:24:29] Selected
> Revit\RCE install Path: (from app.config) C:\Revit2021 [03/15/2021
> 11:24:29] Resolving location of Revit/RevitCoreEngine installation...
> [03/15/2021 11:24:29] Running user application.... [03/15/2021
> 11:24:33] Found an addIn for registration: EnscapeImporter.addin
> [03/15/2021 11:24:33] Initializing RCE.... [03/15/2021 11:24:33]
> Initializing RevitCoreEngine (and possibly running stub installer)...
> [03/15/2021 11:24:33] Language not specified, using English as default
> [03/15/2021 11:24:35] Initialize and  get RCE: (VersionBuild)
> 21.1.20.44 (VersionNumber) 2021 (SubVersionNumber) 2021.2

And eventually a time out:

> [03/15/2021 11:48:59] Error: Retrying on HttpRequestException. Request
> is 'PUT'
> 'https://wlnr5sjl3a.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Prod/v3/workitems/progress'.
> Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred
> while sending the request.  ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read
> data from the transport connection: An existing connection was
> forcibly closed by the remote host..  --->
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was
> forcibly closed by the remote host.    --- End of inner exception
> stack trace ---    at
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError
> error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16
> token)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter
> adapter, Memory`1 buffer)    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at System.Net.Http.Handlers.ProgressMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Polly.Retry.AsyncRetryEngine.ImplementationAsync[TResult](Func`3
> action, Context context, CancellationToken cancellationToken,
> ExceptionPredicates shouldRetryExceptionPredicates, ResultPredicates`1 shouldRetryResultPredicates, Func`5 onRetryAsync, Int32
> permittedRetryCount, IEnumerable`1 sleepDurationsEnumerable, Func`4
> sleepDurationProvider, Boolean continueOnCapturedContext)

I have tested the addin locally using the RVT file in question and it works as expected.

For any Autodesk devs:
The workitem in question is: d25b06b3501c47f9b123ac282aa2e531

Comment: thanks for reporting the problem. From the log above, I don't think anything wrong with the addin, but an error which seems random in the service. Do you keep seeing the same error with the WorkItems?

Comment: Yep still happening today. New workitem 91331faae3844d52a02714763fbfcdc7 still exhibits the same issue

Comment: I checked `d25b06b3501c47f9b123ac282aa2e531` and `91331faae3844d52a02714763fbfcdc7`, both of them are hanging and then timed out. The error on http call posted above didn't fail the workitem. Unfortunely, from the logs, we cannot tell why the addin gets hanging. I will ask help from support team who may contact you directly. Thanks.

Comment: Sean, could you contact forge.help@autodesk.com (cc'ing mikako.harada@autodesk.com) to get more info for us to help troubleshoot? I couldn't find a way to leave a private message. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, Sean. I'm following up.